# How to break a string into specific characters

Tags: c

Im trying to figure how to breakup a string into specific characters, not just to print. Once I break it up into characters i need to store it somewhere and convert it into a different datatype. For example if the user inputs 9*5cos(5), I want to be able to break it up in a way that I can recognize it in int and execute that command. What would be the best way to do this? This has to be executed in C.

Comment: A string is nothing more than an array of single characters, terminated by the null-terminator character `'\0'`. To get the first character it's e.g. `string[0]`.

Comment: What you're describing is called "parsing". You can read books and tutorials on this topic, but it's too broad for a question here.

Comment: `strtol` is a standard c function that parses the initial integer in a string and returns a `long int`. Google this, might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to break a math expression into it's component parts, then you need a [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Lexing or tokeninzing, is the process of transforming your string into tokens that a parser can understand. The parser is the program that will apply rules to tokens and get your result. So, for your example:

```
expr := 9 * 5 * cos(5)
```

We have 8 tokens:

```
1. 9 - NUMBER
2. * - MULTIPLY 
3. 5 - NUMBER
4. * - MULTIPLY
5. cos - IDENTIFIER
6. ( - LEFT_PAREN
7. 5 - NUMBER
8. ) - RIGHT_PAREN
```

So, the output of the lexer stage is a list of tokens (like the one above). The next stage is the parser, which will read in a list of tokens and apply rules. In math, we have some rules like "multiplication takes precedence over addition", and "functions have precedence over multiplication". So you would structure a parser to solve the equation - a common one is a [recursive-descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

You should also look at [Formal Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) and the [Extended Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

In C, if you just want to break the string based on a fixed token, say the space character, you could use [`strtok(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), for example.

```
#include <string.h>
// char *strtok(char *restrict str, const char *restrict delim);

...
char *expr = "9 * 5 * cos(5)"
char *tok;

tok = strtok(expr, " ");
// tok == "9"
tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
// tok == "*"
tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
// tok == "5"
tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
// tok == "*"
tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
// tok == "cos(5)"
tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
//tok == NULL
```